# Positivity of row-sums of a symmetric positive-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can I say that the row-sums of a symmetric positive-definite matrix are positive?
That is, suppose $A$ is SPD and $e$ is the vector of ones. Then prove that each element of the vector $A e$ is positive.

Please also email to markcssfuca@gmail.com

Comment: It's not true. $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 10\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Huh?  If A=your matrix [[1 3];[3 10]] and e=[1;1], then A*e=[4;13], for which every vector element is positive -- so your A is not a counter example.

Comment: Argh, I meant $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -3\\-3 & 10\end{pmatrix},$$ sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Mea culpa, I meant a *positive*, SPD matrix.  I.e., can I say that the row-sums of an *all-positive* symmetric positive-definite matrix are positive?

Comment: No, sorry, let me try again: I meant the inverse of that matrix (since obviously the row-sums of a positive are positive):

Comment: That is (once more): Suppose A is a positive, SPD matrix, and I wish to solve A*x=e, where e=[1;1;1].  Can I say that x is all-positive?

Comment: Let me see. $A$ shall be a positive definite symmetric matrix with only non-negative (strictly positive?) entries. Are the row sums of $A^{-1}$ all positive (non-negative)?

Comment: Yes I'm asking whether the row-sums of A^-1 are all-positive, where A is PD and all elements are positive.  The reason I asked the original question is because the inverse of a PD is again PD.  So I'm asking whether A^-1 e is positive.

Comment: Well, that is "the row sums of $A^{-1}$ [are] all positive", isn't it? No, $$\begin{pmatrix} 10 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -3 \\ -3 & 10\end{pmatrix}.$$ If you want $3\times 3$, write that in the upper left corner, $1$ in the bottom right. Fill with $0$ or really small positive $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Ok, that is indeed a counter example, thanks. So that leaves me wondering what constraints I have to apply on A to make this so -- perhaps diagonal dominance would do.

Comment: Call B=A^-1; since A is SPD so is B.  We wish to solve Ax=e, with e= a vector of 1s. So x=B e: the question then is under what circumstances x is positive (assuming A is all-positive, although we don't need that, below).  At the least, we can say that the sum of x is positive: if the spectral decomposition of A is A=U D U', with D diagonal and positive on the diagonal, then B=U D^-1 U', with D^-1 diagonal with positive diagonal elements.  Premultiplying by e', we have e'x = (e'U) D^-1 (U' e), a sum of positive numbers: so the sum of elements of x are positive.

Comment: @KramWerd: I noticed that you already have set-up e-mail notification in your Preferences. There really is no need for other members to e-mail you personally about the answer, is there?